# How can my program log in to a Web site programmatically with Indy?

Tags: delphi, http, indy

I am trying to log in to fileserve.com from my Delphi application.

I used the LiveHTTPHeader Firefox addon to see HTTP post data. I found

> &autoLogin=on&recaptcha_response_field=&recaptcha_challenge_field=&recaptcha_shortencode_field=&loginFormSubmit=Login

I tried in my application like this:

```
Str := TStringList.Create;
Str.Add('loginUserName='+edit1.Text);
Str.Add('loginUserPassword='+edit2.Text);
Str.Add('autoLogin=on');
Str.Add('recaptcha_response_field=');
Str.Add('recaptcha_challenge_field=');
Str.Add('recaptcha_shortencode_field=');
Str.Add('loginFormSubmit=Login');  
s:= IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.fileserve.com/login.php', Str);
FreeAndNil(str);
s1 := IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.fileserve.com/dashboard.php');
memo1.lines.add(s1);
```

In my my memo, it's not giving the data after I logged in. It just displays the source of the main site. Why doesn't it recognize that I logged in? (I used a working ID and password while testing.)

I am using Delphi 7 and Indy 9; The IdHTTP.HandleRedirect property is set to true.

Comment: I would use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect exactly what was going across the wire and compare it to what a browser sends.

Comment: @Jeff According to the question, "livehttpheader" has been used, which shows all HTTP traffic. Surely Wireshark would be overkill for this. :)

Comment: yeah wireshark is overkill for this ,well any away i did samething for another it worked for that but when i am trying on this its giving strange output :(

Comment: @bzlm presumably Wireshark would not have been overkill, since it would have revealed a difference in traffic between NOP's app versus what the browser was doing (i.e. sending a cookie).  But maybe livehttpheader wasn't being used to its full extent here.

Comment: @Jeff No, the OP just forgot to think about cookies. The Live HTTP Headers add-on shows them. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site you're logging in to probably sends a cookie in its response to the login request. You need to remember that cookie and send it back during all subsequent requests. Indy should have some sort of `TIdCookieManager` object that you can hook up to your `TIdHTTP` object to make it remember cookies automatically.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` automatically creates a `TIdCookieManager` internally if you do not provide one.  Just make sure to visit the page that sends the cookie before then posting to the page that uses the cookie.

Comment: Was that true even in Indy 9, @Remy? The code in the question clearly visits the login page before fetching the next one.

Comment: Yes, TIdHTTP in Indy 9 automatically creates a TIdCookieManager internally (see the implementation inside of `TIdCustomHTTP.ProcessCookies()`).  As for the other issue, it is possible that Indy might be rejecting the login pge's cookie.  Make sure the contents of the TIdCookieManager are being updated after visiting the login page, before visiting the next page.